# "invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character" when using "with" inside of "apply"

Tags: r, apply

I'm applying two conditions to each row in the dataframe `trades1` (basically comparing each row with each other row within one column). `conditions` vector is supposed to consist of 1 when both conditions are satisfied and 0 otherwise.

Data example:

```
  order     date         time           ms price dir amount    hour index i
1 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.567 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     1 1
2 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.574 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     2 2
3 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.577 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     3 3
4 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.585 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     4 4
5 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.587 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     5 5
6 FUT-3 14.02.06 10:00:00.594 1.950535e+16 66.97 BUY      1 5418154     6 6
```

Code:

```
conditions <- apply(trades1, 1, function(x) with(x, as.integer(ms - trades$ms == 1e+6 & price/trades1$price >= 1)))
```

I've checked that `trades1`is a dataframe and that columns are numeric. The error I recieve:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

In case the problem is not with the data argument, but with placing `with` inside of `apply`, I'd appreciate suggestions on how to solve this the other way.

Comment: I've made a typo, it doesn't matter here. As i said, I need a vector ```conditions``` with 1 if a row in ```trades1``` satisfies these two conditions with any other row in ```trades1``` and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that `apply` does is convert its argument into a matrix. Once that's done, `with` doesn't work any more.

If you want to loop over rows (are you *sure* this is the best solution?), use a plain old `for` loop, or `lapply` over a vector of row numbers:

```r
lst <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(trades1)), function(row) { with(trades1[row, ], ...) } )
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Comment: Same problem with RAM here

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Hong Ooi `apply` converts the dataframe to matrix and hence all your numbers are converted to characters. You can correct the `apply` loop by doing

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) as.integer(any(as.numeric(x["ms"]) - df$ms == 1e+6 & 
                                    as.numeric(x["price"])/df$price >= 1)))
```

However, I think a better approach here would be to use `mapply` since you want to check the conditions for `price` and `ms`.

```
as.integer(mapply(function(x, y) 
          any(x - df$ms == 1e+6 & y/df$price >= 1),df$ms, df$price))
```

---

Similar approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ans := as.integer(any(ms - df$ms == 1e+6 & 
                                  price/df$price >= 1)), by = seq_len(nrow(df))]
```

and `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
   mutate(ans = map2(ms, price, 
               ~as.integer(any(.x - df$ms == 1e+6 & .y/df$price >= 1))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running out of RAM when trying this so I can't tell if it solves my problem, but thanks for suggestion

Comment: @aazh yeah..`apply` solutions are considered slow usually. Can you try this with `data.table` ? `setDT(df)[, ans := as.integer(any(ms - df$ms == 1e+6 & price/df$price >= 1)), by = seq_len(nrow(df))]`

Comment: This seems to be faster but still my PC can't handle this